# Bar chart from array of objects

Tags: charts, d3.js

Good afternoon.
I am the user that posted the "Bar chart from array of objects" in stackoverflow.
I need an extra help.

What I need is that in my bar chart appear the xAxis with the values of key and after i sort the data this values as the chart lenght of the bars sort and reset too.

```
var dataset = {key: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], value: [10,20,30,40,50]};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3HL4a/81/

If you do not mind send me the jsfiddle updated.

Regards and one more time thanks.

Comment: You just do `.data(dataset.value)` instead of `.data(dataset, key)`.

Comment: You can explain better I do not understand.

Comment: The example you've linked to has a line of code `.data(dataset, key)`. Assuming that you save your data in a variable `dataset` you need to replace this line with `.data(dataset.value)`.

Comment: I already change it and nothing happens. If you do not mind change the code in jsddle and past the link here.

Thank you friend.

Comment: You also have to put in your data.

Comment: I update the the link if you do not mind see my code http://jsfiddle.net/3HL4a/73/

Comment: One more question. I need to add a xAxis with values od mt data:
In what attr I can do it?

Comment: Use the axis component -- http://jsfiddle.net/3HL4a/75/

Comment: Good morning!
iN ORDER TO THE LAST QUESTIONS HOW i CAN CHANGE THE xAXIS TO THE VALUES INSIDE DATASET VARIABLE (KEY:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference `dataset.value` instead of `dataset` throughout your code and make according adjustments for how to access the data. Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3HL4a/74/).

Comment: When I sor the data the X values are not correcta.
And I need to put the values of dataset.key in the xAxis insted of the its index

Comment: It might be better to post a separate question about this.